# Job for smbd.service failed because a timeout was exceeded

Tags: 22.04

I had installed samba as domain controller in Ubuntu server 22.04 to get access from client machines to share folders but when i checked the status of it was in active and tried to enable it and then started an error message shown "job for samba.service failed because the control process exited with error code"

Comment: If you were given the job of solving a problem like this for someone else, what sort of information would you ask them for?